# Is it possible to access Photoshop file (.psd) in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photoshop

I want to enable/disable layer of .psd file in unity3d using C#.
Is it possible to access photoshop file in unity3d?

Thanks

Comment: on mac I use only .psd files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible use UnityPsdImporter

https://github.com/Banbury/UnityPsdImporter

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for plugins.

Photoshop has an option which you fund under `File` > `Export` > `Layers to files` and choose the file path where your sprites are.

Comment: The question is how to access this option in Unity, not how to do that manually.